# laravel 4.2 eloquent relationship - want to return extra data

Tags: laravel, orm, eloquent

I have a relationship 1:1 a message can have one author (actually User model),

```
models/message.php

public function author()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('User', 'id', 'user_id');
    }
```

This is fine, I get the user model back in this relationship, however I want to add an attribute to the model return in the relationship, basically I want to check if the user model has a password value, if it doesn't set attribute named guest to true.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this

```
public function author()
{
    $user = $this->hasOne('User', 'id', 'user_id');
    if($user->password == "")
    {
       $user['guest'] = 1; //// or something
    }
    return $user;
}
```

This is quick hack hope this helps you

Answer (score 0):

Usually, password field is restricted in User model like this:

```
/**
 * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $hidden = array('password', 'remember_token');
```

If I understood it right, you want to get password value from User model through relationship. You can remove 'password' from $hidden array in User model, but it's recommended not to do it, because your password field can be modified, which can make some problems to your application security. After removing 'password' from $hidden array you will have access to this field.